# Ignoring unused futures with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, future, threadpoolexecutor

I'm running two functions, `fast()` and `slow()`, in parallel using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. If `fast()` returns a non-`None` result, I'd like to use it, otherwise, use the `slow()` result. Here is an example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def fast():
    sleep(2)
    return 'fast'

def slow():
    sleep(4)
    return 'slow'

def run_parallel():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        fast_future = executor.submit(fast)
        slow_future = executor.submit(slow)

        fast_result = fast_future.result()
        if fast_result is not None:
            slow_future.cancel()
            return fast_result

        return slow_future.result()

print(run_parallel())
```

Running that outputs:

```
$ time python example.py 
fast

real    0m4.058s
user    0m0.041s
sys 0m0.011s
```

Since `fast()` returned a non-`None` value, I expected this to take 2s instead of 4s, especially since I have that line to `slow_future.cancel()`.

My ideal syntax for this would be something like:

```
combined_future = fast_future.orElse(slow_future)
return combined_future.result()
```

What can I do to get this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the slow future not being cancellable (`slow_future.cancel()` returns False), so the threadpool executor waits for the thread.
Try something like:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep

abort_flag = False


def fast():
    for i in range(20):
        if abort_flag:
            return None
        sleep(.1)
    return 'fast'


def slow():
    for i in range(40):
        if abort_flag:
            return None
        sleep(.1)
    return 'slow'


def run_parallel():
    global abort_flag
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        abort_flag = False
        fast_future = executor.submit(fast)
        slow_future = executor.submit(slow)
        for f in as_completed((fast_future, slow_future)):
            result = f.result()
            if result is not None:
                abort_flag = True
                return result


print(run_parallel())
```